# BCP No Rows Copied Runs Locally but Not Remotely

Tags: copy, bcp

I built this BCP Call that works perfectly on my DEV host, but not on my PROD host. It is executed by a .bat file on the host that contains this call to BCP. When I run it from an elevated command prompt on the host, it runs fine, but when the same .bat file is executed remotely, it executes, but copies no rows. The input file, data.psv, is the same on both DEV and PROD hosts.

The command is:

`bcp DATABASE.dbo.TABLE in data.psv -S HOSTNAME -f Snowflake_Imp_File_Format6.Fmt -T -b 20000 -e errors.txt -h"TABLOCK"`

Any help is greatly appreciated. I have replaced the HOSTNAME with it's IP and SQL Port, but that didn't work either.

Comment: What do you mean by "remotely"? How is the bcp command executed on the PROD host? how is the batch executed that contains the BCP command?

Comment: @jamie, What I meant by remotely was the R script with  this embedded call to BCP was running on my desktop, which has a drive mapping to the directory path that contained the Snowflake_Imp_File_Format6.FMT, data.psv, and errors.txt files, so it ran fine.  However, I did not have an identical drive mapping that DEV had in my PROD environment, which caused it to fail.  My Solution was to \\hostname\directory\directory\etc to fully  define the UNC path on PROD in the bcp command.  That allowed the R code to run from my desktop (remotely) or directly from a .bat file on the PROD host.